# related to session_start() in php

Tags: mysql, php-5.5

I am new user for PHP.I have working on some php project.want some help regarding session in php.I have login.html page which form action perform to login.js. when login perform,the Username and password has requsted url to login.php page for check username & password in mysql db table and start session_start() and set $_SESSION to username and password. If true then relocated on home.php page with session. but my home.php page content html code with this php code

```
    <?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION["USER"])) { 
        include ('../content/logout.php');
        exit();
    }
?>
```

I have start sessio_start() on login.php.I have check with print_r($_SESSION); for session has been start on not. but its start. when I relocat to home.php it not work. I check it on home.php to print_r but it not shows.I have attached php code written in home.php.
and it shows me error that 
[client 127.0.0.1:53005] PHP Warning:  session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in logout.php........

my logout page contain html code with this php code

```
 <?php
    session_destroy();
    session_unset(); 
?>
```

and relocate to login.html page.

Comment: you have to have `session_start()` on every php file... its more like post... it gets passedevery time

Comment: can you tell me.It is necessory that session_start() need in every page.If we start on login page then why we need to start again in another page

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the session again. Has to be on every page.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["USER"])) { 
        include ('../content/logout.php');
        exit();
    }
?>
```

To use the session vars you allways have to start the session on every php you have. It is kind of like POST without sending ^^ And it has to be befor any output! But you have to tell your php that there is a session and you want to use it.

**EDIT**

See [this quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

> session_start() creates a session OR RESUMES THE CURRENT ONE based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

Comment: can you tell me.It is necessory that session_start() need in every page.If we start on login page then why we need to start again in another page.

Comment: Like i sayed... on further pages its not really starting... session_start is more like a include session than. But ... you just have to add it. This should do it :)

Comment: but suppose I do not add session_start() on that php code. then it works? and if it not work how can we get that without writting session_start on another page(); if somone wants like this..

Comment: There is no other way to store data in a session without adding session_start to every page. Actually you don't have 1000 pages if you code in OOP. You would have a controllerclass that includes the needed php file and the controller contains the session start so its just needed once in this case. But in your case, you obviously need it on every page :) Other ways are storing data in a database or may a cookie...

Comment: Ok :) Thank you for explain in detailed. :) and can you please tell me exact defination of session?

Comment: What do you mean with "exact definition of session" ?

Comment: actually @Dwza my project has also contain more than 400 pages. and defination of SESSION? meance just explain what session and why session in your words. :)

Comment: Sessions in my words, ok: A session is a temporary storage to store data like username, email and stuff that you may need in the routine you running through. If you close the browser the session is mostly killed and the data is lost. So if you have to store date for longer you may need cookies or a database. For larger data i recommend a database. Session is good to e.g. keep the username so if hes on you page you could personalize the page for the user. Like Hello Mr. Overflow, how are you? instead of Hello Sir, how are you?

Comment: POST is to send data from one page to an other one (hidden) GET is to send data from one page to an other one (visible) SESSION is to keep data in all pages as long as its needed (hidden like post)

Comment: @Pratiksha thank me with a vote up and a accept of my answere :)

Answer (score 0):

When server receive an HTTP request, it receives GET/POST/COOKIE data, and has no idea which server-side session the client is related to.

When you call [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) server *creates a session or resumes the current [session] based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.*

So everytime you need a session in php (say: to read/write $_SESSION), you *must* first call the session with `session_start()` and server will either create or load the session based on GET/POST/COOKIE data.

If calling `session_start()` everytime is a pain, use [`session.auto_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) param. Or you might put you `session_start()` in an [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file).